# Early warning for new questions with problematic tags or titles

Tags: script, tags, api-v2.2, comments

Leaves a temporary comment on new Stack Exchange questions with problematic tags or titles. Some of the issues detected by the bot:

- a non-descriptive title
- a vague tag used as the only tag
- all tags used are relatively obscure

If a problem is detected, a temporarily comment is created to encourage the author to edit. The comment is deleted after 5 minutes.

Motivated by the feature request [A warning to those who use only rare/new tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21669); consequently, the logic of tag and title processing is specific to Math site.

[Source on GitHub](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217141720/https://github.com/normalhuman/EarlyWarning) (deleted)